# Generating and saving an .eml file with python 3.3

Tags: python, email, generator

I am trying to generate emails using the standard email library and save them as .eml files.
I must not be understanding how email.generator works because I keep getting the error 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write.'

```
from email import generator
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
active_dir = 'c:\\'

class Gen_Emails(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.EmailGen()

    def EmailGen(self):
        sender = 'sender'
        recepiant = 'recipiant'
        subject = 'subject'

        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg['From'] = sender
        msg['To'] = recepiant


        html = """\
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <p> hello world </p>
            </body>
        </html>
        """
        part = MIMEText(html, 'html')

        msg.attach(part)

        self.SaveToFile(msg)

    def SaveToFile(self,msg):
        out_file = active_dir
        gen = generator.Generator(out_file)
        gen.flatten(msg)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you include the stacktrace?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are supposed to pass an open file (in write mode) to [`Generator()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.generator.html#email.generator.Generator). Currently you pass it just a string, which is why it fails when it tries to call `.write()` on the string.

So do something like this:

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
outfile_name = os.path.join(cwd, 'message.eml')

class Gen_Emails(object):    

    # ...

    def SaveToFile(self,msg):
        with open(outfile_name, 'w') as outfile:
            gen = generator.Generator(outfile)
            gen.flatten(msg)
```

**Note**: `with open(outfile_name, 'w') as outfile` opens the file at the path `outfile_name` in write mode and assigns the file pointer to the open file to `outfile`. The context manager also takes care of closing the file for you after you exit the `with` block.

`os.path.join()` will join paths in a cross-plattform way, which is why you should prefer it over concatenating paths by hand.

`os.getcwd()` will return your current working directory. If you want to your file to be saved somewhere else just change it out accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a modified solution that works with extra headers too. (This was tested with Python 2.6)

```
import os
from email import generator
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

html_data = ...

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = ...
msg['From'] = ...
msg['To'] = ...
msg['Cc'] = ...
msg['Bcc'] = ...
headers = ... dict of header key / value pairs ...
for key in headers:
    value = headers[key]
    if value and not isinstance(value, basestring):
        value = str(value)
    msg[key] = value

part = MIMEText(html_data, 'html')
msg.attach(part)

outfile_name = os.path.join("/", "temp", "email_sample.eml")
with open(outfile_name, 'w') as outfile:
    gen = generator.Generator(outfile)
    gen.flatten(msg)

print "=========== DONE ============"
```