# Directing to Default Mail App with Attachment Python

Tags: python, email, pyqt, attachment, email-attachments

I have been trying to direct the user to the default mail app on pc (or have the user select the mailing app they want) then open the app to send a mail with an attachment already included.

I tried mailto and webbrowser explained here:
[Python: launch default mail client on the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779191/python-launch-default-mail-client-on-the-system)
They work but it is not possible to add attachments automaticaly by these methods anymore. I read it is removed due to some safety issues. Or maybe I could not find how to do that.

I managed achieving what I wanted by using pywin32 with outlook. But it requires the user to have outlook on their pc and not everyone has that.

I dont wanna use something like smtplib, I just want to use whatever mail app there is on the user's PC or possibly somehow direct them to gmail by using chrome or whatever. I want the user to enter their own passwords to the directed app if they were not already logged in. Cannot put any type of passwords into the code.

I could not find any solutions aside from using outlook which is limiting. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you can compose an email draft in MIME format and [write it into an `.eml` file with all the attachments needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837498/generating-and-saving-an-eml-file-with-python-3-3).
Then, use [`os.startfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) to launch the default application for handling email draft.

On Linux, where `os.startfile()` is not available, there is a widely available tool [xdg-email](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-email.html).
You can launch it with `subprocess`:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["xdg-email", "--attach", "1.png", "alice@example.org"])
```

It however, does not implement any standard interface, but tries to guess the application to launch and supports each of them case-by-case:
https://github.com/freedesktop/xdg-utils/blob/8ae02631a9806da11b34cd6b274af02d28aee5da/scripts/xdg-email.in

You can also implement the same logic manually, detect the program to start heuristically and start at least Outlook or Thunderbird. [Thunderbird has a command line interface to create emails with attachments](https://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_-_Thunderbird) with `thunderbird -compose "to=alice@example.org,attachment=...`.

Comment: thanks this helped me. However, appearently regular Windows Mail App can open eml files in read only mode only which kinda defeats its purpose. But at least I got an alternative way to send mails now.